# Append to parent pom property in child pom from command line or pom file

Tags: maven

Suppose that i have some property in parent pom i.e. testProperty

I know that I can replace that value in child pom using:

```
<properties>
    <testProperty>new value</testProperty>
</properties>
```

Is there a way to append in child pom some value to that property?

This does not work:

```
<properties>
    <testProperty>${testProperty} appended value</testProperty>
</properties>
```

I'm looking for the solution where I can do that from command line when executing mvn command but if this is not possible i have to somehow append it inside pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if user-defined properties are available on the command line. But within the POM, you can introduce another property as shown.

Parent:

```
<properties>
    <baseProperty>new value</baseProperty>
    <testProperty>${baseProperty}</testProperty>
</properties>
```

Child:

```
<properties>
    <testProperty>${baseProperty} appended value</testProperty>
</properties>
```